# mysql string to date

Tags: mysql

How can I convert a string/varchar like '12-Mar-2013' to date like 2013-03-12?

I tried

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12-Mar-2013','%Y-%m-%d');

SELECT DATE_FORMAT('12-Mar-2013','%Y-%m-%d');
```

but both return null.

My current database version is 5.5.7-rc.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` converts DATE to STRING.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Try

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12-Mar-2013','%d-%M-%Y');

->   2013-03-12
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('12-Mar-2013','%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%d-%m');
```